# Track error in Travis CI

Tags: symfony, travis-ci

I have Symfony 2.7 application that functionally tested. In local environment, it'easy to track error since I can see the log `on app/logs` directory. But in Travis CI I don't know what to do while my functional test is just shows these kind of lines:

```
1) MyApp\Bundle\SomeBundle\Tests\Controller\SomeControllerTest::testIndexAction
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.
```

So, how to find out what coused the error  in Travis CI ??

Comment: What exactly do you need to find?

Comment: I need to find the exact error or thrown exception that causes 500