# Get symfony error or exception on cli for testing

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

While my unit test failed, it's only shows that the assertion does not meet my requirement.

for this kind of assertion,

```
$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

the failed results is like:

```
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.
```

How to get the exact error or exception  that occured ?

I know I can dumping the response content like this

```
var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

But it prints raw html that hard to read.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u try with: `var_dump($client->getResponse()->getStatus());` ?

Comment: You could check app/logs/dev.log?

Comment: @user2182349 What if the test running on continues integration server like Travis CI.. I don't know how to check the log there, I also have a question about it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164429/track-error-in-travis-ci

Comment: It can be a real pain since 500 just means a general error.  What I do is to enter the url into a browser to get see the error details.  I then fix the error using the browser for testing.  Once the error is resolved then I run the phpunit test again.

Comment: You might also try emailing yourself errors: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_email.html.  Not sure if it will work on travis or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to log with Symfony2 could be:

```
$this->get('logger')->info('messsage');
```

Notice that Monolog (default logger) use Psr interface (namespace Psr\Log): You can log in different app/log/*.log file

Here all method of Psr\Log\LoggerInterface interface:

```
public function emergency($message, array $context = array());
public function alert($message, array $context = array());
public function critical($message, array $context = array());
public function error($message, array $context = array());
public function warning($message, array $context = array());
public function notice($message, array $context = array());
public function info($message, array $context = array());
public function debug($message, array $context = array());
public function log($level, $message, array $context = array());
```